# Disable snapping objects in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape

When I handdraw on my drawing it alway snaps to nearby objects, which is frustrating when drawing details.

How can I disable snapping to objects in Inkscape ?

**Update**
I do not have this button. Any else way to do ? Or any tip, how to get this button ?

[image]

Comment: "This button"? Ah, that's a comment to the answer(s)? Well - you're showing the coloring dialog - there you won't find it. See the main window.

Comment: Its the same dialog like yours I guess, just in German ?

Comment: I'm german and have the same filling & contur dialog, but said button is not in the dialog. Use the main menu, "Anzeige - Anzeigen/Ausblenden - Einrastungsleiste" to make this toolbar visible. It might dock horizontally, not vertically. Junme and Billy Kerr just have the color dialog next to the button, but it's not that dialog. (DE: Der Knopf ist nicht in dem Dialogfenster, sondern das ist bei den Screenshots nur daneben. Geh über das Menü, Einrastungsleiste anzeigen, diese kann auch horizontal erscheinen. Da findet sich der Knopf als erster. Die Reihenfolge im Menü ist identisch mit EN).

Answer (score 31):

make sure snapping dialogue is enabled [image]

the toggle is here
[image]

Comment: They might have as well made the snap controls bar invisible. No sane person would notice it.

Answer (score 9):

Disable snapping by clicking the first icon at the top of the snap bar. This icon toggles the snapping on or off.

[image]

More info here: [Inkscape User Manual](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Snapping.html)

Comment: Thanks for helping. But I can't see that button. I uploaded a Screenshot to the question. Any help ?

Comment: @user1344545 Looks like you have an old version of Inskcape.  My answer is for the latest version 0.92 - the snap bar is located at the extreme right hand edge of the Inkscape application window. Sorry, I can't remember where it was located in old versions.

Comment: Mine too. 0.92.2. Strange :-)

Comment: @user1344545 click on View > Show/Hide > Snap Controls Bar

Answer (score 6):

Use the `%` or `SHIFT` + `5` combination to disable/reset snapping. Based on help [here](https://slackalaxy.com/2017/02/11/disable-snapping-in-inkscape/)

Answer (score 3):

Without disabling snapping from the toolbar, you can disable it *temporarily* while you're moving the object by pressing the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me, and I can't find anywhere in the settings where I might change the key for it.

Comment: @SephReed: I have tested that and it works fine on both Linux and Windows.